# Problems with calculating total price in cart

Tags: javascript, cart, calculation

I'm trying to calculate the total price of my cart. It works when I only select the same product but when I chose another product it just multiplies the number of clicks to the total price. How can I rewrite this so it doesn't multiply the amount of clicks?
GIF of my problem: https://gyazo.com/c273f1d8a3caa3cded6debef52cfadaf

```
const shopContainer = document.querySelector(".shop-content");

let productTitle;
let productDescription;
let productImage;
let productPrice;
let productCategory;
let productId;
let productKey = [];
let productArray = [];

let output = "";

const url = "https://fakestoreapi.com/products";

let data = fetch(url)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      productTitle = data[i].title;
      productDescription = data[i].description;
      productImage = data[i].image;
      productPrice = data[i].price;
      productCategory = data[i].category;
      productId = data[i].id;
      productArray[i] = [
        productTitle,
        productDescription,
        productImage,
        productPrice,
        productCategory,
        productId,
      ];
      productKey[i] = data[i].id;
      localStorage.setItem(productKey[i], JSON.stringify(productArray[i]));
    }
    showApi();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error message:", error);
  });

function showApi() {
  for (let i = 0; i < productArray.length; i++) {
    productId = productArray[i][5];
    output += `
              <div class="product-box">
              <img class="product" src="${productArray[i][2]}" alt="product image">
              <h2 class="product-title">${productArray[i][0]}</h2>
                  <div class="bottom-box">
                  <span class="price">${productArray[i][3]}$</span>
                  <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag add-cart' "data-id="${productId}" onclick="returnKey(${productArray[i][5]})"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
          `;
  }
  shopContainer.innerHTML = output;
}


let inputCart = document.querySelector(".inputCart");

function returnKey(clickedId) {
  cart.classList.add("active");
  console.log(clickedId);

  if (localStorage.length !== 0) {
    let sum = 0;
    Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function (key) {
      productObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
      completeProduct = productObject;
      sum += completeProduct[3];
      if (completeProduct[5] == clickedId) {
        let cartPrice = document.createElement("p");
        let cartTitle = document.createElement("p");
        let cartImage = document.createElement("img");

        inputCart.appendChild(cartPrice);
        inputCart.appendChild(cartImage);
        inputCart.appendChild(cartTitle);

        cartPrice.setAttribute("class", "cart-price")
        cartTitle.setAttribute("class", "cart-title");
        cartImage.setAttribute("src", completeProduct[2]);
        cartImage.setAttribute("width", "75");
        cartImage.setAttribute("height", "75");

        cartTitle.innerHTML = completeProduct[0];
        cartPrice.innerHTML = "$" + completeProduct[3];

        console.log(cartPrice);
        console.log(cartTitle);
        document.getElementById('priceTotal').innerHTML = "Total: " + sum + "$";
        console.log(sum)
      }
    })
  }
};

// function totalSum(cartPrice) {
//   sum = 0;
//   cartPrice = document.querySelectorAll(".cart-price");
//   for (let i = 0; i < cartPrice.length; i++) {
//     sum = sum + completeProduct[3];
//     console.log("Product price " + sum);
//     document.getElementById('priceTotal').innerHTML = "Total: " + sum + "$";
//   }
// }

let removeBtn = document.getElementById("removeBtn").addEventListener("click", clearCart);
let buyBtn = document.getElementById("buyBtn").addEventListener("click", buyCart);

function clearCart() {
  removeCart = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to clear your cart?");
  if (removeCart) {
    inputCart.innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('priceTotal').innerHTML = "Total: " + "0" + "$";;
    console.clear();
  }
};

function buyCart() {
  shopMore = window.confirm("Do you want to checkout?");
  if (shopMore) {
    alert("Thank your for shopping at CatchShop!");
    window.location.reload();
  }
};

let cartIcon = document.querySelector("#cart-icon");
let cart = document.querySelector(".cart");
let closeCart = document.querySelector("#close-cart");

cartIcon.onclick = () => {
  cart.classList.add("active");
};

closeCart.onclick = () => {
  cart.classList.remove("active");
};
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the `totalSum()` function for every item. And `sum` always gets "reset" to 0. Try to add `let sum = 0` before this line `Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function (key) {`

```
function totalSum() {
  cartPrice = document.querySelectorAll(".cart-price");
  let sum = 0; // Everytime this function gets called, sum gets reset
  for (let i = 0; i < cartPrice.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + completeProduct[3];
    console.log(sum);
    document.getElementById('priceTotal').innerHTML = "Total: " + sum + "$";
  }
}
```

Solution:

```
let inputCart = document.querySelector(".inputCart");

function returnKey(clickedId) {
  cart.classList.add("active");
  console.log(clickedId);

  if (localStorage.length !== 0) {
    let sum = 0;
    Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function (key) {
      productObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
      completeProduct = productObject;

      if (completeProduct[5] == clickedId) {
        let cartPrice = document.createElement("p");
        let cartTitle = document.createElement("p");
        let cartImage = document.createElement("img");

        inputCart.appendChild(cartPrice);
        inputCart.appendChild(cartImage);
        inputCart.appendChild(cartTitle);

        cartPrice.setAttribute("class", "cart-price")
        cartTitle.setAttribute("class", "cart-title");
        cartImage.setAttribute("src", completeProduct[2]);
        cartImage.setAttribute("width", "75");
        cartImage.setAttribute("height", "75");

        cartTitle.innerHTML = completeProduct[0];
        cartPrice.innerHTML = "$" + completeProduct[3];

        console.log(cartPrice);
        console.log(cartTitle);
        totalSum(sum);
      }
    })
  }
};

function totalSum(sum) {
  cartPrice = document.querySelectorAll(".cart-price");
  for (let i = 0; i < cartPrice.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + completeProduct[3];
    console.log(sum);
    document.getElementById('priceTotal').innerHTML = "Total: " + sum + "$";
  }
}
```

Edit Solution:

You don't even need the totalSum function. You can simply increase the value of the sum variable with the current price of the local storage object you are iterating.

```
let inputCart = document.querySelector(".inputCart");

function returnKey(clickedId) {
  cart.classList.add("active");
  console.log(clickedId);

  if (localStorage.length !== 0) {
    let sum = 0;
    Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function (key) {
      productObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
      completeProduct = productObject;
      sum += completeProduct[3];
      if (completeProduct[5] == clickedId) {
        let cartPrice = document.createElement("p");
        let cartTitle = document.createElement("p");
        let cartImage = document.createElement("img");

        inputCart.appendChild(cartPrice);
        inputCart.appendChild(cartImage);
        inputCart.appendChild(cartTitle);

        cartPrice.setAttribute("class", "cart-price")
        cartTitle.setAttribute("class", "cart-title");
        cartImage.setAttribute("src", completeProduct[2]);
        cartImage.setAttribute("width", "75");
        cartImage.setAttribute("height", "75");

        cartTitle.innerHTML = completeProduct[0];
        cartPrice.innerHTML = "$" + completeProduct[3];

        console.log(cartPrice);
        console.log(cartTitle);
        document.getElementById('priceTotal').innerHTML = "Total: " + sum + "$";
      }
    })
  }
};
```

Edit:

```
function returnKey(clickedId) {
  cart.classList.add("active");
  console.log(clickedId);

  if (localStorage.length !== 0) {
    Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function (key) {
      productObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
      completeProduct = productObject;
      if (completeProduct[5] == clickedId) {
        let cartPrice = document.createElement("p");
        let cartTitle = document.createElement("p");
        let cartImage = document.createElement("img");

        inputCart.appendChild(cartPrice);
        inputCart.appendChild(cartImage);
        inputCart.appendChild(cartTitle);

        cartPrice.setAttribute("class", "cart-price")
        cartTitle.setAttribute("class", "cart-title");
        cartImage.setAttribute("src", completeProduct[2]);
        cartImage.setAttribute("width", "75");
        cartImage.setAttribute("height", "75");

        cartTitle.innerHTML = completeProduct[0];
        cartPrice.innerHTML = "$" + completeProduct[3];

        console.log(cartPrice);
        console.log(cartTitle);
        let cartElements = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-price');
        let sum = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < cartElements.length; ++i) {
            let item = cartElements[i];  
            let price = item.innerText;
            // Get rid of the $ sign and convert it to int
            sum += parseInt(price.slice(1)); 
         }
         let inputCart = document.querySelector(".inputCart");
        document.getElementById('priceTotal').innerHTML = "Total: " + sum + "$";
      }
    })
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are rewriting the innerHTML of the priceTotal element with the current sum value every cycle of the for loop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).